# Eclipse RCP: Change color of messages in IMessageManager

Tags: eclipse, colors, rcp

I want to change the color of my messages which are added via the `IMessageManager` implementation in a Eclipse RCP environment. I've tried to set the color in the corresponding control but this has no effect.

e.g.

```java
Device device = Display.getCurrent();
Color red = new Color(device, 255, 0, 0);
control.setForeground(red);

messageManager.addMessage(MESSAGE_KEY, message, null, IMessageProvider.INFORMATION, control);
```

How can I achieve this, is there an existing interface which provides this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control you pass to `addMessage` is not the control that is used to display the message. The message is always shown in the `FormHeading` part of the `Form`.

You can set the heading foreground color using

```java
form.getHead().setForeground(color);
```

where `form` is your `Form`.

Don't forget that you must dispose of any `Color` objects that you create when they are no longer needed.